# Simple DB connection with WPF/MEF/Prism failing to initialize

Tags: sql, wpf, mef

I have a database-first Entity Framework model and context generated for me by Visual Studio which are fine when referenced directly from a test project.

However now I am trying to get the context and repository exported through MEF and imported into one of my modules. However when I run the app I get the following error

```
The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.

1) The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

Resulting in: An exception occurred while trying to create an instance of type 'InsuranceManager.Data.Context.InsuranceDataContext'.

Resulting in: Cannot activate part 'InsuranceManager.Data.Context.InsuranceDataContext'.
Element: InsuranceManager.Data.Context.InsuranceDataContext -->  InsuranceManager.Data.Context.InsuranceDataContext -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="InsuranceManager.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")

Resulting in: Cannot get export 'InsuranceManager.Data.Context.InsuranceDataContext (ContractName="InsuranceManager.Data.Context.InsuranceDataContext")' from part 'InsuranceManager.Data.Context.InsuranceDataContext'.
Element: InsuranceManager.Data.Context.InsuranceDataContext (ContractName="InsuranceManager.Data.Context.InsuranceDataContext") -->  InsuranceManager.Data.Context.InsuranceDataContext -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="InsuranceManager.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")

Resulting in: Cannot set import 'InsuranceManager.Data.Repository.InsuranceRepository..ctor (Parameter="context", ContractName="InsuranceManager.Data.Context.InsuranceDataContext")' on part 'InsuranceManager.Data.Repository.InsuranceRepository'.
Element: InsuranceManager.Data.Repository.InsuranceRepository..ctor (Parameter="context", ContractName="InsuranceManager.Data.Context.InsuranceDataContext") -->  InsuranceManager.Data.Repository.InsuranceRepository -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="InsuranceManager.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")

Resulting in: Cannot get export 'InsuranceManager.Data.Repository.InsuranceRepository (ContractName="InsuranceManager.Data.Interface.IDataRepository")' from part 'InsuranceManager.Data.Repository.InsuranceRepository'.
Element: InsuranceManager.Data.Repository.InsuranceRepository (ContractName="InsuranceManager.Data.Interface.IDataRepository") -->  InsuranceManager.Data.Repository.InsuranceRepository -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="InsuranceManager.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")

Resulting in: Cannot set import 'InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule.ViewModel.GeoRegionMaintenanceViewModel..ctor (Parameter="repository", ContractName="InsuranceManager.Data.Interface.IDataRepository")' on part 'InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule.ViewModel.GeoRegionMaintenanceViewModel'.
Element: InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule.ViewModel.GeoRegionMaintenanceViewModel..ctor (Parameter="repository", ContractName="InsuranceManager.Data.Interface.IDataRepository") -->  InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule.ViewModel.GeoRegionMaintenanceViewModel -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")

Resulting in: Cannot get export 'InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule.ViewModel.GeoRegionMaintenanceViewModel (ContractName="InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule.ViewModel.GeoRegionMaintenanceViewModel")' from part 'InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule.ViewModel.GeoRegionMaintenanceViewModel'.
Element: InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule.ViewModel.GeoRegionMaintenanceViewModel (ContractName="InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule.ViewModel.GeoRegionMaintenanceViewModel") -->  InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule.ViewModel.GeoRegionMaintenanceViewModel -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")

Resulting in: Cannot set import 'InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule.View.GeoRegionMaintenanceView.ViewModel (ContractName="InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule.ViewModel.GeoRegionMaintenanceViewModel")' on part 'InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule.View.GeoRegionMaintenanceView'.
Element: InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule.View.GeoRegionMaintenanceView.ViewModel (ContractName="InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule.ViewModel.GeoRegionMaintenanceViewModel") -->  InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule.View.GeoRegionMaintenanceView -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")

Resulting in: Cannot get export 'InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule.View.GeoRegionMaintenanceView (ContractName="System.Object")' from part 'InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule.View.GeoRegionMaintenanceView'.
Element: InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule.View.GeoRegionMaintenanceView (ContractName="System.Object") -->  InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule.View.GeoRegionMaintenanceView -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="InsuranceManager.GUI.MaintenanceModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")
```

Can anyone help me with what this might mean and where to start looking?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll and the EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml files are in the same directory as your running application. In the past this was a non-issue but with EF 6.0 you have to make arrangements to ensure the SQL Server Provider (EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll) is found at runtime. The easiest way I found is to nuget-it for the project using EF 6.0. There are some other considerations documented in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj730568#noProvider that I recommend to become familiar with. HTH

Another way to solve it (I just did) is to add the following line of code to the ctor of the class using EF:

```
var typeOfSqlProviderServices = typeof(System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices);
```

It just worked for me.